# OAuth2 and authorization clarification

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Spring Cloud Dataflow reference documentation indicates that authorization are not managed with OAuth2. When I connect to the application, after a successfull login, I'm redirected to the `/roles-missing`.
I tried to disable the authorization without success:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      security:
        authorization:
          enabled: true
```

My `application.yml` is copied from https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/master/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local/src/main/resources/application.yml

I uncommented the following block with my own OAuth2 server informations:

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: true
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: myclient
      client-secret: mysecret
      access-token-uri: http://127.0.0.1:9999/oauth/token
      user-authorization-uri: http://127.0.0.1:9999/oauth/authorize
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://127.0.0.1:9999/me
```

I'm using spring cloud data flow `1.2.0.M3`.
My OAuth server is Keycloak.

How can I disable role checking?

Comment: Hi, @Guillaume. Could you share the entire YAML file? It could be the other props in the file that's clashing. Also, we do not have `/roles-missing` endpoint in SCDF - it seems like your OAUTH server itself is redirecting it. Where you're running the server, logs, and its version would be useful for troubleshooting.

Comment: That's interesting. I don't have my full environment so I can't give you the logs yet but I updated my questions with all the informations I already have.